# mocha - callback to "end" never gets called?

Tags: mocha.js

I'm new to mocha, and am trying to implement a new test. I'm finding that the callback to my  `end` method never gets called

```
it('should allow valid urls', function(){
  var myUrl = "http://localhost:8080/test";
  api.get(myUrl)
    .end(function(err, res) {
       console.log('THIS IS THE END, MY FRIEND');
     });
});
```

Does anyone know why? I've tried `expect` with a callback as well, and it never gets called too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that `mocha` does analysis of the function arguments, and I'd forgotten to put an argument in my mocha callback - even though it's never referenced in my function or any visible code at all!

So the solution was simply to add a variable, `done` as a function parameter to my `it` function, and it worked, even though it's not visibly used in the immediate context ;-)

```
it('should allow valid urls', function(done){
...
```

EDIT: Note that `done` should be used in my callback, as mentioned by @ oligofren, but I hadn't gotten to that point yet and was surprised to see the callback itself not firing.

Comment: This is wrong. If you are not calling `done`, your test is not doing what you believe it does. The pattern is "call `done()` when you are finished, or call `done(err)` to signify an error, `err` being whatever err you caught". What I fail to understand is why you don't simply get a timeout, which is what happens if you fail to call `done()` within 2000ms (the default timeout).

Comment: @oligofren - Thanks for the feedback... But I'd say it wasn't really wrong, it was just incomplete. I was new to mocha and had simply put a callback there and expected it to be called, so I just put a `console.log('hi')` in it. When it didn't get logged, that's what confused me. Ultimately of course my callback has a call to `done` now that I can see the callback being fired.

Comment: Actually I can see that mocha is being passed a 120s timeout value at the command line, so that's why I wasn't getting a timeout in 2s as well.